# Shell script: for loop will not print files

Tags: bash, glob

Please tell me why this script won't print the file names in the home directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

d="$HOME"

for f in $d
do
        echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `$d` by `"$d"/*`.

Answer (score 1):

`$HOME` expands to the home directory of the invoking user, e.g. `/home/foobar`, so variable `d` will just contain this string, not what is inside the directory.

You can leverage an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=( "$HOME"/* )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

- The array `files` will contain the name of the contents inside `$HOME`
- `"${files[@]}"` expands to the elements of the array `files`, the quotes are important to prevent word splitting, and pathname expansion by shell
- We are iterating over the array elements using a `for` loop

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I am getting a syntax error when using ( ).

Comment: @IBWEV Whats the exact error message? Are you on `bash`?

Comment: You are right.  I was in sh, not bash.  It works great in bash.  Thank you for the help.